# How to convert multi-value answers into single column in Google Forms' response sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have a [Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd-gDlQes15sgdTpQcbjobc1tvLuBJMfA2L9YFJeiRPZNBgKg/formResponse) that asks for Name and up to 3 Score.  The data is dumped [into a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_aLcJ_JV-Kuf46wxOQN0J13z93MT2GpXdfDqMTiyTc/edit?usp=sharing) like this

[image]

But that data is not very convenient. I want to have the data like this...

[image]

Can I do that by adding a new sheet to the workbook, and some kind of `LOOKUP` formula?  Or can I change the settings on the FORM to write up to 3 rows per submit?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet too?

Comment: @user0 sure, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Timestamp", "Name", "Score"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!C2:E<>"", TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 TO_TEXT('Form Responses 1'!A2:B)&"♦"}), , 999^99))&'Form Responses 1'!C2:E&"♠", ))
 , , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠"))), "♦"), "where Col3 is not null", 0))}
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wf76rIE5mfyaWoJiWxH3kab12xjCm7cksCSOYkCOz1w/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: awesome thanks!  that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll need the same king of transformation except for the data type. Looking at the demo sheet, if I replace score values with a text string in the Form Responses 1 sheet, the value is shown on the results (like a null value).
I tried to understand why... but novice here.

Removing statement "where Col3 is not null", line is shown but with an empty Score value.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152934)